# What is the highest power of 8!

Tags: number-theory

What is the highest power of 8! that divides 354!
I know the formula for k = [n/p] + [n/p^2]+ ...
but I don't understand how to use it here

Comment: Well, the primes that divide $8!$ are $2,3,5,7$.  Compute the orders of each (using your formula).  Now do the same for the orders of those primes as divisors of $354!$.  To save time note that $7$ is probably the limiting prime, but I'd take a look at $2$ as well, just because such a high power of $2$ divides $8!$.

Comment: Thanks, I've found that 8! = 2^7 * 3^2 * 5 *7

Comment: Ok, and what about $354!$?  (you only need the powers of $2,3,5,7$).

Comment: It's 345! =2^354 * 3^175 * 5^86 * 7^58

Comment: I got a different answer for $ord_2(354!)$.  I agree on the others (I did it fast so I might be wrong).

Comment: Should note:  just for the sake of rigor you should write $354!=N\times 2^a\times 3^b\times 5^c\times 7^d$ where $\gcd(N,2\times 3\times 5\times 7)=1$.  We don't care what $N$ is but it sure isn't $1$.

Comment: sorry, in 354! power of 2 is 350

Comment: Yes, that's what I got.  And now you can read off your answer!  Somewhat to my surprise, $7$ is not the limiting prime after all.

Comment: it's like I need to divide power of 7 in 354! by one's in 8!?

Comment: Well, all four primes.  But yes.  Looking at powers of $7$ only we see that $\frac {58}1=58$ so it looks like we might be able to get $8!^{58}$ but it turns out that the other primes get in the way of that.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean(

Comment: Well, using your result we see that $8!^{58}=2^{7\times 58}\times 3^{2\times 58}\times 5^{58}\times 7^{58}$.  Unfortunately, $7\times 58>350$ so the power of $2$ is too high.  Turns out that $2$ is the limiting prime here.

Comment: so, it is 50, that's right?

Comment: Exactly.  There you go!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$8! = 2^7 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$$
For $354$, as @lulu pointed out, we only need certain powers.

Clearly, there are fewer $7$s in $354!$ than any other number.

$$\lfloor 354/7 \rfloor + \lfloor 354/49 \rfloor + \lfloor 354/343 \rfloor = 58$$

However, since there $2, 3$ are not to the first power, we have to consider them.

Repeating the process for $2$ gives us $350$ and $350/7 = 50$

Therefore, it must be $50$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use Legendre formula (which you already know ) to find the highest power of $2,3,5,7$ dividing $354!$ and combined it with the fact that $8!= 2^7*3^2*5*7$ . You need to check for   $2's,3's,5's$ as well because there is a possibility that you run out of them while dealing with  $7$ only.